# Callback not fired on google-sign-in

Tags: javascript, google-signin, google-authentication, google-api-js-client

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="MY_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function onSignIn(googleUser) {
                    console.log("Succesfully Singed in!!!");
            }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

With the above I can see a google-sign-in button which opens a pop-up accepts credential and signs me in. But I expect **onSignIn** method to be triggered when the sign in is successful, which is NOT happening.
Does anyone have any pointers at this?

*Tried it on apache server on osx with safari, chrome and firefox browsers*

Comment: the first script tag is malformed

Comment: do you see any errors on console?

Comment: No errors. Even onfailure etc methods are not triggered too.Should I include any apis other than platform.js?

Comment: did you include <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">? https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

Comment: Yes. Updated with full html file.

Comment: and of course, you created a Google Developers Console project and client ID?

Comment: Yes. And can be sure of that as I am able to log in successfully.

Comment: Any chance you've found the answer? I'm seeing a very similar problem. If I sign in with a user for the first time onSignIn doesn't get called. However when I log that user out and sign in with the exact same user it gets called.

Answer (score 3):

In my case : `The callback function was inside the body tag`.

> Callback function not work if it is in body tag, move it to head tag.

Answer (score 2):

You should add your platform.js script in head tag

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="MY_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com" />
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer>    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function onSignIn(googleUser) {
                console.log("Succesfully Singed in!!!");
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this did it for me

Comment: In my case the problem was the browser extension Adblock / Ghostery. I needed to disable it to get the response.

Comment: I had to disable Privacy Badger.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com) and see if **Authorized redirect URIs** is pointing to the origin you are running the JavaScript?

Comment: No. I haven't set any Redirect URLs. Should that matter? The guide says it can be left empty.

Comment: You might want to check "Authorized JavaScript origins" if you specify localhost you also need to specify a port. Example: http://localhost:5000   the redirect uri is optional but the origin is required.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the success event wasn't firing because I was trying to hook up a function from an external js file, included on the page. For some reason, the callbacks will only work if the hooked-up functions appear on the very same page.

Never seen anything like this before. I wonder how they check for this.

Answer (score 1):

It's so late to answer but I think somebody will need this:

- Remember to add origin URI at google console
- If you don't see anything of onSignIn on the terminal, let check at the console of your browser

Answer (score 0):

After defining the function in the body, the only thing that fixed it was setting `window.onSignIn = onSignIn`

```js
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    ...
}
window.onSignIn = onSignIn // <-- this was necessary
```